# Как получить содержимое папки в android

Tags: java, android, файловая-система

Допустим у меня есть такой путь из корня системы `/sdcard/downloads/`
Как мне узнать есть ли в этой папке, ещё какие-то папки или файлы или она пустая?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы получить список файлов директории используйте следующий пример:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/folder";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Если `files == null` то в директории пусто

и не забудьте permission на read external storage

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: А как проверить пустой ли он?

Comment: File[] files = directory.listFiles(); - если files == null то пустой